# How to convert visible control characters back to non-printing characters (opposite of 'cat -v')?

Tags: shell, cat

Given the content of the file which was the result of `cat -v` conversion such as:

```
M-*M-;M-LM-]M-n
```

How can I convert back the file to the original binary format?

---

For example, given the following shell commands:

```
$ printf aabbccddee | perl -lne 'print pack "H*", $_' | cat -v > file
$ cat file
M-*M-;M-LM-]M-n
```

I'd like to do the opposite, so convert visible control characters to their original non-printing characters.

Comment: I'm not sure you can reverse it, at least not losslessly. For example, if you have a file that contains a null byte, cat -v will output `^@`. If you have a file with the characters `^@` in it, cat -v will output the same thing. If your file is longer than 64k, your odds of reconstructing it correctly are not good. Is an imperfect translation OK for your application?

Comment: Any ideas/tricks may help, doesn't need to be 100% lossless, as I'm doing that for obfuscation/education purposes.

Comment: Well at least for the GNU Coreutils implementation, you can read the source file `cat.c` and figure it out yourself - all the rules appear to be in a nested conditional starting at `if (show_nonprinting)`

Comment: ... so for your particular input, where the `128 + 32 <= ch < 128 + 127` rule applies for every octet, you can simply add 128 to the ordinal value of the character e.g. `... cat -v | perl -lpe 's/M-(.)/sprintf "%.2x", 128 + ord($1)/ge'`

Comment: If you're not required to use `cat -v` as the asciifier, it may be easier to use `uuencode` and its inverse, `uudecode`, which will be lossless.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, `base64` perhaps?

Comment: @ilkkachu Sure, that or `uuencode -m`